# How to add date and time to a file name in Windows Media Encoder - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows Media Encoder to record my screen. Whenever there is a recording already there the encoder gives a prompt to overwrite the file. If I press "Yes" by mistake, then the recording gets lost. I want to know if there is a way to add a date and time to the filename so that there will be no clash in the file name. I am adding a screenshot of the filename field in question. Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If there is no obvious user option, that enables this feature (which appears to be the case), you will have to find a different tool that does have this desired option.

Comment: `I want to know if there is a way to add date and time to the filename so that there will be no clash in the file name.` -- The solution would seem to be to type it in manually as part of the archive name. Is there a reason why this isn't possible?

Comment: Yes, we can manually type what ever name we want. But I accidentally clicked yes to the dialog box that asks for confirmation and two hours of screen recording got overwritten. So I was wondering if I could add date and time so that there would be no clash at all